# Perl not recognizing input file uninitialized $filename

Tags: perl, shell

I am calling a perl program from a bash script. This Perl script works when I flag its arguments from the command line but when I call it from the bash script it gives an error.

Here is the relevant part of the bash script:

```
for ((i=1; i<=$z; i++))
do 
    if (($i%2 == 0)); then
         ~/Desktop/SNP_finder.pl `awk 'FNR == '$i <"${d}".fasta` `awk ...` "${d}".txt
    else
...
```

and the Perl script:

```
local $, = "\t";
my @read = split('', $ARGV[0]);
my @reference = split('', $ARGV[1]);
my $filename = $ARGV[2];
...
open(my $fh, '>>', $filename) or die;
print $fh "Reference ", "SNP ", "Location\n";
...
```

I can run `SNP_finder.pl` fine from the terminal window but when I pipe it to this Bash script it gives me the error `Use of unitialized value $filename` and claims the value of `$filename` is `''`.

Comment: Please show the whole `awk` commands used in the script. How do you run the command from the terminal window?

Comment: I know the `awk` commends are fine because the piping works fine without adding the file name. But they are:

`awk 'FNR == '$i <"${d}".fasta` and `awk 'FNR == 2' <"${d}".fasta`

Comment: Perhaps it might be worth copying your `~/Desktop/SNP...` command except changing the name of the `perl` program to `echo` to see what the `awk` commands (and the filename expansion) are becoming inside your script?  It seems that if it works from the command line but not within the script, there's something different in the environment inside the script (some variable not initialized or some other setting or a different location) that is causing the problem.  You know what the `awk` commands give you on the command line, but what about from inside the script?

Comment: That is, right before running the perl script, add these lines:  `echo $(awk 'FNR == '$i <"${d}".fasta)`, `echo $(awk ...)`, and `echo "${d}".txt` to see what you're actually getting.  It's likely different from what you think you're getting.

Comment: I got it to work turned out to be a pretty stupid mistake on my part (was editing the file on my desktop and not in my repo) will probably delete this question sorry about that

Comment: @quantik  Nice that you caught it, but it seems to me that the question still raises valuable points, nicely addressed in the answer, too.  I'd leave it (not delete).

Comment: Few notes. Here isn't anything what you can done in `awk` and can't in `perl`. So, me suggesting you replace every `awk` piece with `perl` and you need master only one language. And for you the perl is especially good, because on the CPAN are zilion modules for dealing with FASTA files and much-much more modules for bio-informatics... Just my 2 cents. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell is performing word splitting. If your awk scripts return empty, the `"${d}".txt` parameter will end up as `$ARGV[1]` or `$ARGV[0]`. If your awk scripts return a string containing whitespace, it will end up further down...

To avoid this, you should quote them, like this:

```
"`awk ...`"
```

Even better would be:

```
"$(awk ...)"
```

Comment: I know the `awk` scripts are not returning empty because it works perfectly fine without passing the file name as a parameter to the perl script. But I shall try this.

Comment: Did not work. I believe it has to do with the passing of the text file as an argument not the `awk` scripts.